# MongoDB aggregation performance improvements

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

- **Number of Documents:**  16 million
- **Number of Documents after matching on aggregation pipeline:** 6 million
- **Sample Document:**

```
{
    "_id": 30,
    "b_id": 123,
    "map_vu_cnt": 30,
    "srch_vu_cnt": 30,
    "wsite_vst_cnt": 30,
    "dir_vst_cnt": 30,
    "created": ISODate("2019-09-30T00:00:00Z"),
    "updated": ISODate("2019-09-30T00:00:00Z"),
    "day": ISODate("2019-09-30T00:00:00Z"),
    "cal_cnt": 30,
    "active": true,
    "year": 2019
}
```

- **Aggregation Query:**

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "b_id": {
                "$in":biz
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$year",
            "count": {
                "$sum": "$dir_vst_cnt"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

- **biz:** Contains ~4k unique b_id. For each business there would be nearly equal number of documents
- **Mongo Db version:** 3.4
- **Machine configuration:** Octacore + 16GB Ram
- Indexes exists on b_id and year
- Collection is unsharded
- The query is taking **13-14 sec** time which is unacceptable for us.

**Question:**

1) How to improve the performance here?
   I searched and didn't find anything helpful.

2) Is mongo a good option for aggregations with large data sets ?